# Otros usos de la etiqueta <link>

Tags: html, html5

Aparte del ya tradicional uso para relacionar hojas de estilo de cascada:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

¿existe algún otro uso del elemento `<link>` que sea útil en una página web? ¿el estándar HTML5 da alguna luz al respecto?

Comment: Una buena idea es buscar por aquí https://www.w3.org/ . Aqui algunas referencias del elemento Link: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H59.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aunque como bien dices, `link` se utiliza principalmente para hojas de estilo CSS, también permite enlazar otro tipo de información, dependiendo del valor del atributo `rel`. Cómo lo interprete el navegador variará según el tipo de recurso que sea (en algunos casos se mostrará, en otros se tratará como meta-data).

Por ejemplo, `link` permite enlazar:

- Información del autor: `author`. Yo incluyo el siguiente código para asociar la página con mi perfil de Google+ (sí, debo ser el único que lo usa :P):

  ```
  <link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/118137220962857817327" />
  ```
- Icono de página: `icon` o `shortcut icon`. Hace que el navegador muestre el icono junto al título de la página (en la ventana o la pestaña):

  ```
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://url.a.mi/fav.ico" />
  ```
- Información de ayuda: `help`. Para enlazar una página que proporcionará ayuda adicional sobre la página:

  ```
  <link rel="help" href="https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/articulo-relacionado" />
  ```
- La siguiente página en una secuencia: `next`. Si estás en una página que sigue un orden (por ejemplo un tutorial), permite indicar qué página debería ser la siguiente. Un ejemplo real tomado de la [página web de NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/):

  ```
   <link rel="next" title="Numpy license" href="license.html" />
  ```
- La anterior página en una secuencia: `prev`. Similar al anterior, pero en lugar de la siguiente, apunta a la página anterior:

  ```
   <link rel="prev" title="NumPy" href="index.html" />
  ```

Puedes encontrar otros ejemplos de los tipos permitidos en la [página de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Tipos_de_enlaces).

Answer (score 1):

La etiqueta Link tiene distintos tipos de uso que no son unicamente utilizados para incluir una hoja de estilo (css) en una web pero si es verdad que por defecto es usado para "linkear" a otros archivos,documentos,imagenes,etc.

Por ejemplo:

Para definir el favicon de una web (Icono que se ve en la pestaña del navegador se usa el tag **link** de la siguiente forma:

```
<link rel="icon" type="img/ico" href="img/favicon.ico">
```

Además podes utilizarla para definir la relación entre las paginas y el transcurso de la web. Son atributos que normalmente no se utilizar pero están avalados y recomendados por la w3c.

Ejemplo:

```
<link rel="previous" href="anterior.html" />
<link rel="next" href="proximo.html" />
<link rel="contents" href="../actual.html#toc" />
```

Otro uso que se le da habitualmente es definir una estilo pero no para la web sino para la impresion de dicha web.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

Te dejo un link donde podes ver un poco mas detallado el uso del tag, entre otras cosas  "[Link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp)".

Comment: Hola @Fakux, respuestas que solo contienen un enlace no son consideradas buenas respuestas por la comunidad. Debes explicar el contenido de ese enlace en tu respuesta y dejar el enlace sólo como referencia adicional. Por favor lee: [¿Como escribo una buena respuesta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Hola, gracias por la corrección, ya mejore mi respuesta.